# Add shadow to border of modal bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I add a shadow to the border of modal bottom sheet? Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          bottomSheetTheme: const BottomSheetThemeData(
              modalElevation: 1000.0,
              elevation: 1000.0,
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20))))),
      home: TabBarDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Press'),
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return Container();
                    });
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

Even though I've set the [`elevation`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet/elevation.html) property, I don't see any shadow on the border of the bottom sheet. Instead I see a plain border:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shadow is controlled by setting either the `BottomSheetThemeData.modalElevation` property or the `elevation` parameter in the call to `showModalBottomSheet`. `BottomSheetThemeData.elevation` appears to do nothing in my example. The shadow is not prominent and not controllable as with `BoxShadow`, but at least clipping works properly. In my question, the shadow was visible, but it was spread out because of the large `modalElevation` value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use boxShadow for this. Try this code.

```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Press'),
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return Container(
                  height: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(30)),
                    boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey, blurRadius: 10.0)],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if the container has a scrollable widget like a ListView, the content is not clipped to the rounded border when you scroll. You have to have the `BottomSheetThemeData` defined as I have in order for the clipping to work, but that results in the shadow getting truncated.

Comment: add padding in the container for fix that